# How to get HashiCorp Vault policy right?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Here is the situation: **I created an user**

`vault write auth/userpass/users/'username' password='password' policies=default`

with **default policy** and **added path**

```
"secret/db_pass/*" {
  capabilities = ["create","read","delete","update","list"]
}
```

in the **default policy**. But when I am trying to access `secret/` I am **getting error** `'You don't have access to secret/,` though I have added permission in the policy file.

Am I doing something wrong? Could some gentle soul please help? Let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: try to read the policy (vault policy read xxx) and make sure that you updated the right capabilities

Comment: Yes. 'vault policy read default' it's there with correct capabilities. path "secret/db_pass/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "delete", "update", "list"]
}

Comment: Maybe try to add a new policy and add it to the user. Try to get a token for the user and perform a token lookup to make sure you have the right capabilities

Comment: Seems structure of policy has been changed. This is how I am achieving it now:

path "secret/*" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}
path "secret/data/db_pass" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "delete", "update", "list"]
}

Comment: If you got it right, please write an answer and set it as the right one :)

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but seems policy structure had been changed. In order to access "secret/db_pass/*" you should be having permission to access secret/ itself. So, I am achieving it with 2 policies. One to get access to secret/ and other for secret/db_pass/*.

```
path "secret/" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}

path "secret/db_pass/*" 
    { capabilities = ["create","read","delete","update","list"] 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In KV v2, you will need to add `data/` after `secret/` in the second policy.

You will also need to add `*` after `secret/` in the first policy.

So Ashit's solution would be:

```
path "secret/*" {
capabilities = ["list"]
}

path "secret/data/db_pass/*" 
{ 
 capabilities = ["create","read","delete","update","list"] 
}
```

Comment: It seems that secret/data/db_pass/* delete policy provide capability to delete keys in secrets but not the secrets itself. So, to be able to delete secrets you have to add same policy twice  with metadata in path in second policy: 
* path "secret/metadata/db_pass/*" {
  capabilities = ["create","read","delete","update","list"]
} *

Answer (score 0):

My demo-acl (It's working on HashiCorp Vault 1.14.0)

```
# User can list all secret path
path "secret/*" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}

# User can read specific secret path
path "secret/metadata/dev/apps/appA" {
  capabilities = ["read", "list"]
}

# User can update specific secret path
path "secret/data/dev/apps/appA" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
```